# Proving $\oint{u \nabla v d\vec{r}}$ = $-\oint{v \nabla u d\vec{r}}$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

My approach was to assign $dv =\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}dx + \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}dy + \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{z}}dz$ , $du =\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}dx + \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}dy + \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{z}}dz$ , $u=u$, and $v=v$

then using the partial fraction formula:
$$\oint{v \nabla u d\vec{r}} = u.v - \int{v du} = u.v - \int{v . \nabla u d\vec{r}} = -v\nabla ud\vec{r}$$

this assumes that $ du = \nabla u .d \vec{r} $ and I am not sure if that assumption is corrrect as I am unsure if me assuming $\iiint \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}dx + \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}dy + \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{z}}dz= u$ is correct.

Can I get any insight if what I am doing is incorrect and maybe a hint on how to apprroach this correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: You want to use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem applied to $\nabla(uv) = u\nabla v + v\nabla u$ (or you can modify the general proof of this theorem to your case if you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the fundamental theorem of line integrals that $\oint \nabla(uv) d\vec{r} = 0$.  Since $\nabla(uv) = u \nabla(v) + v \nabla(u)$, you get the result by integrating both sides.